# Blocking bad requests with .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, spam-prevention

I have a site that is getting hit by users hitting variations of this URL 
/index.php?s=

I am trying to block all requests to the following string which should get rid of all the spammers **php?s=**

The problem I seem to be having is the ? and = in the htaccess file are protected characters and I just can't get the syntax correct. How can I use **php?s=** in the following scenarios?

I have tried

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>  RewriteEngine On
>  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.(*php?s=).* [NC]
>  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*php?s=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}.* [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

and

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>  RewriteEngine On
>  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(php?s=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}).* [NC]
>  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

But nothing works.  Help please!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#all .php requests with s= in querystring
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.+\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=.*$   [NC]
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

If you want to prevent `s=` in any querystring location replace the 2nd rewritecond above with

```
#block s= in any location
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?s=.*$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try blocking them before they get to the point of executing anything

[.htaccess example](https://gist.github.com/1377722)