# htaccess block GET request to specific URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Reuqest:

```
    "GET /api/get_recent_posts/?dev=1&page=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 40831 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 0.5; en-us) AppleWebKit/522+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/419.3"
```

Trying to block requests using the below but not working

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
    RewriteRule ^api/get_recent_posts/(.*)$ - [F,NC]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/get_recent_posts/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236341/blocking-bad-requests-with-htaccess-file

Comment: Saw it already, couldn't make use of it to resolve this.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/586206/block-certain-requests-starting-with-specific-string-using-htaccess-in-apache

Comment: I updated with a second attempt from that link however no go, I think the issue is with the end of the URL: 
`code`?dev=1&page=1`code`

Comment: where is this url coming from and why you want to block it  as it does not contain any extension of the language developed

Comment: The URL does actually work, but there is hundreds of IP's hitting it which is flooding the server so we are looking to block all requests to it.

Comment: How are you testing whether the rules work or not?

Comment: Watching the access logs, all the requests coming in are throwing 200 codes, no 403

Comment: And can you be sure that mod-rewrite is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /api/get_recent_posts/\?dev=([^\s&]+)&page=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```